# Why do ANSI color escapes end in 'm' rather than ']'?

Tags: colors, escaping, language-agnostic, history, ansi-escape

ANSI terminal color escapes can be done with `\033[...m` in most programming languages. (You may need to do `\e` or `\x1b` in some languages)

What has always seemed odd to me is how they start with `\033[`, but they end in `m` Is there some historical reason for this (perhaps `]` was mapped to the slot that is now occupied by `m` in the ASCII table?) or is it an arbitrary character choice?

Comment: Have you looked at the full list of the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)?

Comment: Oh. that makes more sense. I figured it was an off-by-one error or something since the values for `]` and `m` are 16 slots apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely arbitrary, but follows a scheme laid out by committees, and documented in [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) (the same as ISO 6429).  Except for the initial <kbd>*Escape*</kbd> character, the succeeding characters are specified by ranges.

While the pair <kbd>*Escape*</kbd><kbd>**`[`**</kbd> is widely used (this is called the control sequence introducer ***CSI***), there are other control sequences (such as <kbd>*Escape*</kbd><kbd>**`]`**</kbd>, the *operating system command* ***OSC***).  These sequences may have parameters, and a *final byte*.

In the question, using ***CSI***, the **`m`** is a *final byte*, which happens to tell the terminal what the sequence is supposed to do.  The parameters if given are a list of numbers.  On the other hand, with ***OSC***, the command-type is at the beginning, and the parameters are less constrained (they might be any string of printable characters).

Answer (score 3):

A bit of extension for [Thomas Dickey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49224293/21409054) answer.

Section 8.3.117 of ECMA-48 describes "**SGR** - SELECT GRAPHIC RENDITION" control function:

> Notation: (Ps...)
>
> Representation: CSI Ps... 06/13
>
> Parameter default value: Ps = 0
>
> SGR  is  used  to  establish  one  or  more  graphic rendition  aspects  for  subsequent  text.

According to Section 5.4 "Control sequences", control function **is identified** by the **Final Byte**. And Table 3 "Final Bytes of control sequences without Intermediate Bytes" also states that code `06/13` means `SGR` control function.

Look at column 6, row 13 of the [ASCII code table](https://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/chapter2.html#T2-1): character `m` is here (in other words, character with code `0x6d` is `m`).

So, the idea is: the SGR function (which manages text appearance) has code 06/13. We call this function by its code (addressing functions by names is fairly modern concept;)). Code of the function, when treated as a character code, corresponds to the letter `m`. So, you don't need to write all this digits, just one letter, it is so convenient:)

`m` is not meaningful letter, it's just substitution for the numerical. So, your question should be "Why SGR function has code 06/13?" and the answer is: "Look at the aforementioned Table 3. It was play of chance."

By the way, **CSI**  is  represented  by  bit  combinations  01/11  (representing  ESC)  and  05/11  (`[`) in  a  7-bit  code  **or by  bit  combination 09/11 in an 8-bit code**. So, in modern 8-bit environment you can get rid of escaping, and just use single control character for CSI:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
CSI = '\x9b'  # 09/11: Control Sequence Introducer
SGR = '\x6d'  # 06/13: Select Graphic Rendition
P = '32'      # green display
print(f'{CSI}{P}{SGR}Hello, green world!{CSI}0{SGR}')
```